# SQL script, are my scripts accurate?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

Okay, so I received my graded exam that I took last week, that is on SQL using Oracle Plus. Two of the questions that I answered were marked wrong, but I feel strongly that I am correct, but he is insisting that my answer is wrong... So I was hoping someone here could clarify whether or not my answer is correct!

1.) The first question stated: 
"Display the dog ids and names of those which were not treated in May 2003"

So using previously created databases, one being called 'dog' and the other was named 'treatment'.

*Note* Both tables filled with values The dog table consisted of values for the dog id's, name, etc and the treatment table consisted of treatment_id, foreign key(dog_id) referencing dog_id from the table dog, treatment_date and a few other fields...

So my answer was:

```
SELECT dog.dog_id, dog.name, treatment.treatment_date 
FROM dog, treatment 
WHERE treatment.treatment_date NOT BETWEEN '01-MAY-03' and '31-MAY-03'
AND dog.dog_id = treatment.dog_id;
```

But he said it was wrong...
"--No, these are treated NOT IN MAY"

2.) My second question was
"Find all the doctors who ever treated a dog adopted with the lowest adoption fee. Note that there may be more than one dog adopted with the lowest adoption fee. List the doctor's ids and the dog ids. Order the result by doctor ids in ascending order and for each doctor by dog ids in ascending order."

So using other tables which we created before the exam, one named **'adoption'** with attributes of **'vet_id'** a foreign key which references vet_id from a table called vet, and **'dog_id'** another foreign key; and also using another table named **'treatment'** with attributes **'vet_id'** a foreign key which references vet_id from a table called 'vet', **'dog_id'**, and **'treatment_fee'**

*Note - **'treatment_fee'**'s lowest value or fee for this exam was '15'.

My Answer Was:

```
SELECT treatment.vet_id, adoption.dog_id 
FROM adoption, treatment 
WHERE adoption.dog_id = treatment.dog_id
AND treatment.fee = '15' 
ORDER BY treatment.vet_id;
```

But again he said this was wrong...

So, I hope somebody here could help me and help give me an answer to this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue #1 - your query returns "all dogs who had treatments that weren't in May", not "all dogs that did not have treatments in May". Note that if a dog had a treatment in both April and May, that dog would show up in your query.

Issue #2 - the question is asking about "adoption fee", but you're looking at the lowest "treatment fee".

Comment: you are so correct lol I just realized that mistake, I meant to put adoption.fee not treatment.fee!!! wow I do deserve this grade

Answer (score 2):

First answer:

```
SELECT dog.dog_id, dog.name
  FROM dog
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT treatment.id
                      FROM treatment
                     WHERE tratment.dog_id = dog.id
                       AND treatment.treatment_date BETWEEN '01-MAY-03' and '31-MAY-03'
                  )
```

Second one:

```
SELECT distinct treatment.vet_id, treatment.dog_id
  FROM adoption, treatment 
 WHERE adoption.dog_id = treatment.dog_id
   AND dog.adoption_fee = (SELECT MIN(d2.adoption_fee)
                          FROM dog d2 )
 ORDER BY treatment.vet_id, treatment.dog_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

For question #1:

You current JOIN mechanism would not list the dogs that don't have treatments in because the `dog.dog_id = treatment.dog_id` condition would not list dogs that didn't have such a treatment.

What you need to do is specifically find the dogs that had treatment in that month and remove them from the overall set of dogs. You might need to consider a subselect like this:

```
SELECT dog_id
FROM dog
WHERE dog_id NOT IN (SELECT dog_id FROM treatment WHERE treatment_date BETWEEN '01-MAY-03' and '31-MAY-03')
```

For question #2:

First of all, I would mark down because you hard coded the minimum fee when you should find the minimum fee dynamically from the table data. I also wonder whether you mixed adoption fee and treatment fee. In my answer below, I assume there is an adoption_fee filed in adoption table. You also didn't bother to implement the second sort condition.

You need to determine the minimum adoption fee, then determine the set of dog ids that have that adoption fee, then join that with vet id who gave treatment to those dog id's

```
SELECT t.vet_id, a.dog_id
FROM treatment AS t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT dog_id FROM adoption
WHERE adoption_fee IN (SELECT MIN(adoption_fee) FROM adoption)) AS a
ORDER BY t.vet_id ASC, a.dog_id ASC
```

Bottom line, it was correct that your answers with noted as wrong.

Comment: for the second question, I had written above the answer a query that found the lowest price, I forgot to include that in this in my question.

Comment: @user3018918 Were you asked to do it in a single query?  Did he note that you should have used an adoption fee instead of a treatment fee?  Did he note that you didn't apply second level of sorting?